# How can I find which combinations of a set of numbers will sum to three numbers?

Tags: python

I don't even know where to even take this - Python?  Excel?  Just Google it?  (FWIW, my numbers are making up an Excel table.  I've been just trying to select a few and guess it, but no bueno.)

I have these numbers:

```
826, 583, 212, 976, 385, 198, 662, 133, 212, 583, 211, 519
```

I want to figure out which sets to pull together to make these numbers:

```
1047, 2453, 2000
```

(both sets add up to 5500).

Any thoughts about how to figure that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))


for p in powerset([826, 583, 212, 976, 385, 198, 662, 133, 212, 583, 211, 519]):
    if sum(p) in [1047, 2453, 2000]:
        print(p)
```

Output

```
(385, 662)
(826, 976, 198)
(583, 212, 198, 662, 133, 212)
(212, 198, 662, 133, 212, 583)
(583, 212, 133, 212, 583, 211, 519)
(583, 212, 385, 198, 133, 212, 211, 519)
(212, 385, 198, 133, 212, 583, 211, 519)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried something similar:

```
from itertools import combinations, islice

a = [826, 583, 212, 976, 385, 198, 662, 133, 212, 583, 211, 519]

for combo in range(2, len(a)+1):
    c = combinations(a, combo)
    for i in c:
        tot = sum(islice(i, combo))
        if tot in [1047, 2000, 2453]:
            print(f"Sum of {i} is {tot}")
```

It returns:

```
Sum of (385, 662) is 1047
Sum of (826, 976, 198) is 2000
Sum of (583, 212, 198, 662, 133, 212) is 2000
Sum of (212, 198, 662, 133, 212, 583) is 2000
Sum of (583, 212, 133, 212, 583, 211, 519) is 2453
Sum of (583, 212, 385, 198, 133, 212, 211, 519) is 2453
Sum of (212, 385, 198, 133, 212, 583, 211, 519) is 2453
```

I'm first looping through the different number of combinations we can have - 2 till len(list).
And for each of those number of combinations, I'm getting the combination of numbers and seeing if the total adds up.

This will probably get very slow if your list gets large.